# Generics in a dictionary used for mapping

Tags: c#, generics, mapping

I am trying to do something, that might be completely a** backwards. I don't know if I have confused myself, and just need a kick in the right direction or I need to completely rethink everything.

I am working on a simple mapper. The mapper maps from one object property to another object property.

First take was just a simple Dictionary that would map one property name to another. But for the next version I need to do some conversion as well. So I am thinking I will expand the map a little.

Dictionary where MyMap is a class that has two properties on it. A string which corresponds to the string above, and a Func which is the conversion Func. My code will then look for the Func and if present use it to convert the value before applying it on the object mapped to.

My problem is that I would like to have the Func take a bool as input if it is a boolean property, a string if it is a string property etc. For example something like this:

```
dictionary.Add("Open", new MyMap {Name = "Closed", Map = Func<bool, bool> {x => !x}};
dictionary.Add("AmountUsd", new MyMap {Name = "AmountEur", Map = Func<decimal, decimal> {x => x * conversionRate}};
```

I can't do that with generics as far as I can gather. The Funcs cannot have different signatures.

I could of course just have a Func and then cast the value inside the Func, but that isn't as nice.

Have a I confused myself completely, or is there another approach that I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the class generic, then make a dictionary that contains a non-generic base type:

```
interface IMyMap {
    ...
}
class MyMap<T> : IMyMap {
    public Func<T, T> Map { get; set; }
}

var dict = new Dictionary<string, IMyMap> {
    { "Open", new MyMap<bool> { ... }
};
```

Obviously, you will not be able to interact with the type parameter from the dictionary, since you don't know what type it is.

Comment: OK... my problem was that I was trying to interact with the map from the dictionary by adding some convenience methods. What would the IMyMap interface look like? The interface needs to know about the generic type doesn't it? Or would I just not put the generic map in the interface?

Comment: @JayPete: Because you can't have a dictionary of a non-homogenous generic type.  What you're trying to do is rather tricky (if you want to avoid boxing), and depends on _exactly_ how you're consuming the type.

Comment: I have tried creating the interface IMyMap without the Map property, and then casting it to MyMap<T> when I need it. But 'var mapper = _map[propertyName] as MyMap<typeof(value)>;' doesn't work.

Comment: If I hardcode MyMap<bool> for example it works as I want. So I just need to figure out how to cast it correctly.

Comment: @JayPete: Generic parameters must be known at compile time.  You wouldn't be able to do anything with that anyway.

Comment: Well ok then. I guess I will just have to create a switch where I check for the type at run time, and then repeat the two lines of code I have for each type. Not that nice, but a way through, and since it is hidden behind an API, people won't be exposed to it. Thanks!